# table with columns and a div in full length of table

Tags: css

How is it possible to do something like this?

I need a table with some columns (in the example 3) and a div (the blue box) that has the full length of the table? The height of each row has to adapt the heigth relative to the div height

[image]

### jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Have you considered using the `colspan` attribute? Demo: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NXS44/).

Answer (score 0):

In the first cell on the row:

- set the cell to `position:relative`
- put a DIV in the cell with `position:absolute`, then set `top:`, `left:`, `width:`, `height:`  and your background  colour.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/8hg7F/

Comment: This doesn't work properly in FireFox, they stack: http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/8hg7F/1/.

Comment: As far as I know, "position: relative" can't be applied to any of table elements. Did you test it directly in a browser?

Comment: there is another problem.. all widths/heights are not fixed but relative to each other

Comment: isn't it possible with float and then clear:both so the td will expand around the div

Comment: Try using `margin-top:` to position the divs relative to their starting position. When using `position:absolute` `top:` will set the absolute position of the div.
http://jsfiddle.net/8hg7F/3/